# Пузырьковая сортировка на python 3 не понятно почему переменные i и j так работают

Tags: python

```
N = 5
a = []
for i in range (N):
   a.append (randint (1,10))

for i in range (len (a) - 1):
   for j in range (len (a) - i - 1):
      if a[j] > a[j + 1]:
         # вывод итерации
         print ("[  i = " + str(i) + "  ]", "[  j = " + str(j) + "  ]")
         # swapping...
         a[j], a[j + 1] = a[j + 1], a[j]
```

**А вот результат:**

Список из рандомных чисел

```
-
[96, 3, 3, 52, 89, 41, 37, 50, 66, 70]

[swapping...]
-
[96, 3, 3, 52, 89, 41, 37, 50, 66, 70]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 0  ] [  j = 0  ]
-
swapping: -> [3, 96]
-
[3, 96, 3, 52, 89, 41, 37, 50, 66, 70]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 0  ] [  j = 1  ]
-
swapping: -> [3, 96]
-
[3, 3, 96, 52, 89, 41, 37, 50, 66, 70]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 0  ] [  j = 2  ]
-
swapping: -> [52, 96]
-
[3, 3, 52, 96, 89, 41, 37, 50, 66, 70]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 0  ] [  j = 3  ]
-
swapping: -> [89, 96]
-
[3, 3, 52, 89, 96, 41, 37, 50, 66, 70]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 0  ] [  j = 4  ]
-
swapping: -> [41, 96]
-
[3, 3, 52, 89, 41, 96, 37, 50, 66, 70]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 0  ] [  j = 5  ]
-
swapping: -> [37, 96]
-
[3, 3, 52, 89, 41, 37, 96, 50, 66, 70]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 0  ] [  j = 6  ]
-
swapping: -> [50, 96]
-
[3, 3, 52, 89, 41, 37, 50, 96, 66, 70]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 0  ] [  j = 7  ]
-
swapping: -> [66, 96]
-
[3, 3, 52, 89, 41, 37, 50, 66, 96, 70]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 0  ] [  j = 8  ]
-
swapping: -> [70, 96]
-
[3, 3, 52, 89, 41, 37, 50, 66, 70, 96]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 1  ] [  j = 3  ]
-
swapping: -> [41, 89]
-
[3, 3, 52, 41, 89, 37, 50, 66, 70, 96]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 1  ] [  j = 4  ]
-
swapping: -> [37, 89]
-
[3, 3, 52, 41, 37, 89, 50, 66, 70, 96]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 1  ] [  j = 5  ]
-
swapping: -> [50, 89]
-
[3, 3, 52, 41, 37, 50, 89, 66, 70, 96]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 1  ] [  j = 6  ]
-
swapping: -> [66, 89]
-
[3, 3, 52, 41, 37, 50, 66, 89, 70, 96]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 1  ] [  j = 7  ]
-
swapping: -> [70, 89]
-
[3, 3, 52, 41, 37, 50, 66, 70, 89, 96]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 2  ] [  j = 2  ]
-
swapping: -> [41, 52]
-
[3, 3, 41, 52, 37, 50, 66, 70, 89, 96]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 2  ] [  j = 3  ]
-
swapping: -> [37, 52]
-
[3, 3, 41, 37, 52, 50, 66, 70, 89, 96]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 2  ] [  j = 4  ]
-
swapping: -> [50, 52]
-
[3, 3, 41, 37, 50, 52, 66, 70, 89, 96]
-
iteration...
-
[  i = 3  ] [  j = 2  ]
-
swapping: -> [37, 41]
-
[3, 3, 37, 41, 50, 52, 66, 70, 89, 96]
-
sorted...
-
[3, 3, 37, 41, 50, 52, 66, 70, 89, 96]
-
```

Почему так происходит ? Почему переменные **i** и **j** так меняются ?
А почему вообще переменная **i** до 8-й итерации не меняет значения ? Если переменная **i** не меняет значение как тогда срабатывает внутренний цикл ? Я понял сам алгоритм, но как он работает тут уже не понимаю оказывается. Я специально добавил вывод итерации, чтобы увидеть все явно! Не понимаю почему переменные так работают... Профи проясните мне пожалуйста... :)

Comment: `if a[j] > a[j + 1]:` потеряли тут `i`?

Comment: А что ты ожидал увидеть?

Answer (score 6):

Переменные действуют просто перебором.

**Пример!** У вас есть пару коробок с кубиками - чтобы каждый перебрать Вам нужно достать из каждой коробке по кубику.

Но Вы же не будете сразу лезть во все коробки.
Вы сначала пойдете в одну коробку, там все кубики переберете, потом вторую, и т.д.

В итоге будет Ваш план такой:
1 (коробка) 1 (кубик),
1 2,
1 3,
1 4,
2 1,
2 2,
2 3,
2 4,
3 1...

Теперь просто учитывая, что начинается отсчëт от 0, идет такой перебор, который переставляет числа в нужные места и, **словно пузырьки в воде**, числа выплывают на нужные позиции)

Надеюсь, вам стало понятнее)

Comment: Боже мой! Спасибо вам большое!!! Дошло черт возьми! Уважаю!

Answer (score 1):

Потому что сначала работает внутренний цикл до конца, а только потом идёт следующая итерация внешнего.